# simplify code in depth first search function call

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I am one of the many hanging around stack overflow for knowledge and help, especially those who are out of school already. Much of my CS knowledge is learnt from this excellent web. Sometimes my question can get quite silly. Please forgive me as a newbie.

I am working on the [Largest Divisible Subset](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-divisible-subset/) problem on leetcode. There are many good solutions there, but I try to solve with my own thought first. My strategy is turning this problem into a combination problem and find the largest one who meets the divisible requirement.I use depth-first search method and `isDivisible` to create such a combinations. All the combinations I found meet the divisible requirement.

Here is how I would code to conduct all possible combinations of a given sequence.

```
def combinations(nums, path, res):
    if not nums:
        res.append(path)
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        combinations(nums[i+1:], path+[nums[i]], res)
```

Following is my code to create a combination of all possible divisible subsets. The code is almost exactly the same as the above code, except that that I add `isDivisible` to determine whether or not to add the nums[i] to the  `path`.

```
def isDivisible(num, list_):
    return all([num%item==0 or item%num==0 for item in list_])

def dfs(nums, path, res):
    if not nums:
        res.append(path) 
        return 
    for i in range(len(nums)):
#         if not path or isDivisible(nums[i], path):
#             path = path + [nums[i]]
#         dfs(nums[i+1:], path , res)
        dfs(nums[i+1:], path + ([nums[i]] if not path or isDivisible(nums[i], path) else []), res)


path = []
res = []
dfs(nums, [], res)

return sorted(res, key=len)
```

It works fine (almost got accepted but exceeded the time limit for large input) because of the performance of dfs. My question here is how I can simplify the last line of code in `dfs` by moving `([nums[i]] if not path or isDivisible(nums[i], path) else [])` out of the function call, which is too bulky inside a function call. I tried to use the three lines in the comment to replace the last line of code, but it failed because `path` will propagate every `nums[i]` who meets the condition to next `dfs`. Could you please teach me to simplify the code and give some general suggestions. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your method, check first to see if it would get accepted.

Here is a bit simpler to implement solution (which I guess it would be one of Stefan's suggested methods):

```
class Solution:
    def largestDivisibleSubset(self, nums):
        hashset = {-1: set()}
        for num in sorted(nums):
            hashset[num] = max((hashset[k] for k in hashset if num % k == 0), key=len) | {num}

        return list(max(hashset.values(), key=len))
```

Here is LeetCode's DP solution with comments:

```
class Solution(object):
    def largestDivisibleSubset(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        if len(nums) == 0:
            return []

        # important step !
        nums.sort()
        
        # The container that keep the size of the largest divisible subset that ends with X_i
        # dp[i] corresponds to len(EDS(X_i))
        dp = [0] * (len(nums))
        
        """ Build the dynamic programming matrix/vector """
        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            maxSubsetSize = 0
            for k in range(0, i):
                if nums[i] % nums[k] == 0:
                    maxSubsetSize = max(maxSubsetSize, dp[k])

            maxSubsetSize += 1
            dp[i] = maxSubsetSize
        
        """ Find both the size of largest divisible set and its index """ 
        maxSize, maxSizeIndex = max([(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(dp)])
        ret = []
        
        """ Reconstruct the largest divisible subset """ 
        # currSize: the size of the current subset
        # currTail: the last element in the current subset
        currSize, currTail = maxSize, nums[maxSizeIndex]
        for i in range(maxSizeIndex, -1, -1):
            if currSize == dp[i] and currTail % nums[i] == 0:
                ret.append(nums[i])
                currSize -= 1
                currTail = nums[i]
        
        return reversed(ret)
```

I guess maybe this LeetCode solution would be a bit closer to your method, is a recursion with memoization.

```
class Solution:
    def largestDivisibleSubset(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        
        def EDS(i):
            """ recursion with memoization """
            if i in memo:
                return memo[i]
            
            tail = nums[i]
            maxSubset = []
            # The value of EDS(i) depends on it previous elements
            for p in range(0, i):
                if tail % nums[p] == 0:
                    subset = EDS(p)
                    if len(maxSubset) < len(subset):
                        maxSubset = subset
            
            # extend the found max subset with the current tail.
            maxSubset = maxSubset.copy()
            maxSubset.append(tail)
            
            # memorize the intermediate solutions for reuse.
            memo[i] = maxSubset
            return maxSubset
        
        # test case with empty set
        if len(nums) == 0: return []
        
        nums.sort()
        memo = {}
    
        # Find the largest divisible subset
        return max([EDS(i) for i in range(len(nums))], key=len)
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-divisible-subset/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: thank you very much for your help and I am grateful for that. However, I am not trying to find an answer to solve the problem but to simplify my code and improve it. Later (guess now) I can compare how my code performs compared to others code and think about how other people think of an excellent way to do that. I updated my question a little. Could you give me any help further? I am still thinking and see whether I can improve my code.

Comment: My strategy is turning this problem into a combination problem and find the largest one who meets the divisible requirement. I use the depth-first search method and ```isDivisible``` to create such a combinations. All the combinations I found will meet the divisible requirement. Then I choose the one with longest length.